# Is the following linear in the choice variables?

Tags: constraints

I have a constrained optimization problem and need to show that the constraint is concave.

Similar problem usually have linear constraints, so they don't need to worry about it.

However, I am not sure if my constraint is concave.
I have the following constraint:
$$a +x*y = b,$$
where $a$ and $b$ are parameters and $x$ and $y$ are choice variables.
Is this constraint linear?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

No! This does not describe a straight line in the X-Y plane. The general form for a linear restriction would be $ax+by=c$, where you are free to choose your parameters $a,b,c$